# why is Enumerable Concat repeating here?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm trying to get a single value inside an enumeration before ordering it, as per the code below. The value shows up twice.

Why? What's the best fix?

Cheers,
Berryl

```
    private static IEnumerable<Currency> _commonCurrencies;

    public static IEnumerable<Currency> GetCommonCurrencies() {
        return _commonCurrencies ??
               (_commonCurrencies
                = Currency.GetCachedCurrencies()
                      .Concat(new[] {Currency.Get(CurrencyIsoCode.KWD)})
                      .Where(x => !x.AlphabeticCode.StartsWith("X", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                      .OrderBy(x => x.AlphabeticCode));
    }
```

output

```
...
JPY
KWD
KWD  // repeats?
...
```

## EDIT

Currency.GetCurrencies() is making a call to an implementation of a Thread Safe cache which wraps a Dictionary and returns its values:

```
public ICollection<TValue> Values { get { return _inner.Values; } }
```

I do not own this type. Changing the code to 'slap' a ToArray() fixes the problem so that the concat value only shows up once and is an acceptable solution. Not sure why it shows up twice without forcing the enumeration, although threading seems to be at the root..

Comment: Does `Currency` implement `Equals`?

Comment: @CodeInChaos. it does...

Comment: Then you can slap on a `Distinct()` call.

Comment: GetCachedCurrencies() probably also returns KWD.  As @CodeInChaos said Distinct() should work

Comment: @CodeInChaos. I sure can, but why would it repeat in the first place? do you know?

Comment: @Berryl perhaps `Currency.GetCachedCurrencies()` already contains one. `Concat` is used to combine sequences, `Union` is used to combine sets.

Comment: @AnuragRanjhan. I wouldn't be doing the concat in the first place if that were true :--). That isn't the case here

Comment: @CodeInChaos. Understood, but that is the oddity. Currency.GetCachedCurrencies() does NOT contain the element.

Comment: Then give us code that reproduces the problem. Lazy evaluation might cause your unexpected behavior. Perhaps you need to slap on a `ToArray()`/`ToList()` call.

Comment: "Currency.GetCachedCurrencies() does NOT contain the element." -- not even after `Currency.Get(CurrencyIsoCode.KWD)` is called? Order of evaluation may be misleading, but effectively, the `GetCachedCurrencies()` needn't do any work until you actually start enumerating, and at that point, the results may already have changed.

Comment: Isn't there a chance that `GetCommonCurrencies` is called from multiple theads? That way, and with `_commonCurrencies` being static, KWD could get added to the result more than once. Other than that, I second the notion of you providing us with the code with which the problem can be reproduced.

Comment: @CodeInChaos. Fair enough and close enough (see edit) if you want to put your comments into an answer. Cheers

Comment: @Nikola Anusev. Absolutely the likely cause, see edit. Cheers

Comment: @Berryl Good, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Like @CodeInChaos said, it is probably because of [Lazy Evaluation](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/02/20/visual-linq-watch-query-expressions-as-they-happen.aspx) if GetCachedCurrencies does not contain the element.

I put together a small program and I only get 1 instance of 'KWD'.

```
enum CurrencyIsoCode
{
    USD,
    KWD,
    JPY,
    XCD,
    TVD
}

class Currency
{
    public Currency() : this(false) { }
    public Currency(bool inner) { }

    public static IEnumerable<Currency> GetCachedCurrencies()
    {
        return new[] { 
             new Currency () { currencyCode = CurrencyIsoCode.USD },
             new Currency () { currencyCode = CurrencyIsoCode.JPY },
             new Currency () { currencyCode = CurrencyIsoCode.XCD }
           };
    }

    public  CurrencyIsoCode  currencyCode { set; get; }

    public string AlphabeticCode
    {
        get { return currencyCode.ToString(); } 
    }

    public static Currency Get(CurrencyIsoCode isOCode)
    {
        return new Currency() { currencyCode = isOCode };
    }
}

class Program
{
    private static IEnumerable<Currency> _commonCurrencies = null;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var currencies = GetCommonCurrencies();

        foreach (var curr in currencies)
            Console.WriteLine(curr.AlphabeticCode);

        Console.Read();
    }


    public static IEnumerable<Currency> GetCommonCurrencies() 
    {
        return _commonCurrencies ??
           ( _commonCurrencies
            = Currency.GetCachedCurrencies()
                  .Concat(new[] {Currency.Get(CurrencyIsoCode.KWD)})
                  .Where(x => !x.AlphabeticCode.StartsWith("X", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                  .OrderBy(x => x.AlphabeticCode));
    }       
}
```

Comment: Nikola's analysis of a multiple thread call seems likeliest at this point. See edited post. Cheers